# Why does javascript onchange event only work in first row update from a data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

[image: Data table]

From within the first modal (opened from the first table row's 'Edit' button) the autosum is triggered no problem - in the modal window linked to the first row.

But if I click on any other row's 'Edit' button to launch it's modal - and then I change number the 'select' input value, the alert(x1) shows data from first row table(id=27)  - as if the javascript function is not being processed but the id(28) is passed to the modal.

[image]

I tried find the solutions in stackoverflow..but i don't find any solutions..please helps me.

i will show the codes

**Button to Modal**

```
<a href="#" data-id="{{$devStatus->devID}}" class="badge badge-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdit{{$devStatus->devID}}"><i class=" far fa-edit"></i> Edit</a>
```

**Modal Edit Data**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalEdit{{$devStatus->devID}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Device Details Status</h5>
                                                            {{$devStatus->devID}}
                                                        </div>
                                                      
                                                        <form  action="{{ route('recall.updateDeviceStatus',[$devStatus->devID]) }}" name="totalUpdate" id="totalUpdate" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="needs-validation" novalidate>@csrf
                                                        {{method_field('PUT')}}
                                                           
                                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="application_id" name="application_id" value="{{ $application_id }}" hidden readonly>
                                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="device_id" name="device_id" value="{{ $device_id }}" hidden readonly>
                                                                
                                                                <div class="form-group row">
                                                                    <label class="col-lg-5 col-form-label ">1.  Product Number / <br>Catalogue Number: </label>
                                                                    <div class="col-9 col-lg-7">
                                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="final_devProductNum" id="final_devProductNum" value="{{$devStatus->devID}}" >
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                        
                                                                <div class="form-group row">
                                                                    <label class="col-lg-5 col-form-label ">2.  Lot / Serial  No: </label>
                                                                    <div class="col-9 col-lg-7">
                                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="final_devBatchNo" id="final_devBatchNo"value="{{$devStatus->final_devBatchNo}}">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                    
                                        
                                                                <div class="form-group row">
                                                                    <label class="col-lg-5 col-form-label ">3.  Quantity remaining in <br>warehouse: <b>(x)</b></label>
                                                                    <div class="col-9 col-lg-7">
                                                                        <input  type="number"  class="form-control " placeholder="unit" min="0" name="final_devQuantityWarehouse" id="final_devQuantityWarehouse2" value="{{$devStatus->final_devQuantityWarehouse}}">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                    
                                        
                                                                <div class="form-group row">
                                                                    <label class="col-lg-5 col-form-label ">4.  Quantity Recalled: <b>(a)</b></label>
                                                                    <div class="col-9 col-lg-7">
                                                                        <input  type="number"  class="form-control " placeholder="unit" min="0" name="final_devQuantityRecalled" id="final_devQuantityRecalled2"value="{{$devStatus->final_devQuantityRecalled}}">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                        
                                                                <div class="form-group row">
                                                                    <label class="col-lg-5 col-form-label ">5.  Quantity consumed <br>by customers:<b>(b)</b> </label>
                                                                    <div class="col-9 col-lg-7">
                                                                        <input  type="number" class="form-control " placeholder="unit" min="0" name="final_devQuantityCust" id="final_devQuantityCust2"value="{{$devStatus->final_devQuantityCust}}">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                        
                                                                <div class="form-group row">
                                                                    <label class="col-lg-5 col-form-label ">6.  Quantity Unindentified: <b>(c)</b></label>
                                                                    <div class="col-9 col-lg-7">
                                                                        <input type="number"class="form-control " placeholder="unit" min="0" name="final_devQuantityUnidentified" id="final_devQuantityUnidentified2"value="{{$devStatus->final_devQuantityUnidentified}}">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                        
                                                                <div class="form-group row">
                                                                    <label class="col-lg-5 col-form-label ">7.  Quantity Disposed: <b>(p)</b></label>
                                                                    <div class="col-9 col-lg-7">
                                                                        <input  type="number" class="form-control " placeholder="unit" min="0" name="final_devQuantityDisposed" id="final_devQuantityDisposed2"value="{{$devStatus->final_devQuantityDisposed}}">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                        
                                                                <div class="form-group row">
                                                                    <label class="col-lg-5 col-form-label ">8.  Quantity Returned to <br> Manufacturer: <b>(q)</b></label>
                                                                    <div class="col-9 col-lg-7">
                                                                        <input  type="number" class="form-control " placeholder="unit" min="0" name="final_devQuantityReturned" id="final_devQuantityReturned2"value="{{$devStatus->final_devQuantityReturned}}">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>

                                                                <div class="form-group row">
                                                                    <label class="col-lg-5 col-form-label ">9.  Total affected  unit: <br> <b>(z=x+y)</b></label>
                                                                    <div class="col-9 col-lg-7">
                                                                        <input  class="form-control"  name="final_devAffectedUnit" id="final_devAffectedUnit2" value="{{$devStatus->final_devAffectedUnit}}" readonly >
                                                                        <h6 style="color:red;font-family:italic;">* Auto Sum based on user input</h6>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>

                                                                <div class="form-group row">
                                                                    <label class="col-lg-5 col-form-label ">10.  Quantity sold:<br><b>(y=a+b+c)</b> </label>
                                                                    <div class="col-9 col-lg-7">
                                                                        
                                                                        <input  class="form-control" name="final_devQuantitySold" id="final_devQuantitySold2" value="{{$devStatus->final_devQuantitySold}}"  readonly >
                                                                        <h6 style="color:red;font-family:italic;">* Auto Sum based on user input</h6>
                                                                        
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                                
                                                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                                                                <button type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-primary">Clear</button>
                                                                <button data-id="{{$devStatus->devID}}" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </form>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    
    $(document).ready(function(){

       
        
        $(document).on('change', "#totalUpdate", function(){
            
    
            
            var a1 = Number($('#final_devQuantityRecalled2').val());
            var b1 = Number($('#final_devQuantityCust2').val());
            var c1 = Number($('#final_devQuantityUnidentified2').val());
            var x1 = Number($('#final_devQuantityWarehouse2').val());
            alert(x1);
            

            var y1 = a1 + b1 + c1 ;
            
            
            
            
            var z1 = x1 + y1 ;
            
            
            $('#final_devQuantitySold2').val(y1);
            $('#final_devAffectedUnit2').val(z1);
            

        
        });
    });
</script>
```

I also try the on change function on the modal..but the output is undefined :(. Heres is my code

**Modal edit Data**

```
<form  action="{{ route('recall.updateDeviceStatus',[$devStatus->devID]) }}" name="totalUpdate" id="totalUpdate<?= $devStatus['devID']?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="needs-validation" onchange="show_value('totalUpdate<?= $devStatus['devID']?>')" novalidate>@csrf
                                                        {{method_field('PUT')}}
```

**onchange function javascript**

```
 <script>    
    function show_value(getTotal) {
    selected_value = document.getElementById(getTotal).value;
    alert(selected_value);
    
    }
</script>
```

**alert(selected_values)**

[image: outcome alert]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might be that you're reusing ID tags. Hard to tell, but you can try this method. It finds the form elements relative to the select menu's form.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', "#totalUpdate", function() {
    let form = $(this).closest('form')
    let a1 = Number(form.find('[name=final_devQuantityRecalled2]').val());
    let b1 = Number(form.find('[name=final_devQuantityCust2]').val());
    let c1 = Number(form.find('[name=final_devQuantityUnidentified2]').val());
    let x1 = Number(form.find('[name=final_devQuantityWarehouse2]').val());
    let y1 = a1 + b1 + c1;
    let z1 = x1 + y1;
    $('#final_devQuantitySold2').val(y1);
    $('#final_devAffectedUnit2').val(z1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you it's works!! the auto sum on id=final_devQuantitySold2 and id=final_devAffectedUnit2 is working based on 'select' input value (using alert (y1)) but not updated on the input value.

Comment: i solved the problem from code :-
$('#final_devQuantitySold2').val(y1);
$('#final_devAffectedUnit2').val(z1);

to the:-
Number(form.find('[id=final_devQuantitySold2]').val(y1));
Number(form.find('[id=final_devAffectedUnit2]').val(z1));